# Communication between two Django applications

Tags: python, django, rest

I have one Django application that has a model Patient which has all the information about the patient and it's blood sample. I wish to have another application that have some fields of the Patient model and I want both the applications to communicate using some sort of web services so the changes made in the first application are reflected in the second .

The two applications are running on different servers and have different databases.

I'm a novice in Django, please share any resources anyone has. If my question is not clear enough, please let me know with a comment.

Thank you

Comment: Why you need two different web service?

Comment: i don't want two different web service i want a single web service

Comment: Right, so there is no need fur "communication". Sounds like you just want a foreign key from one model to the other.

Comment: see actually what i'm trying has no practical use but i just want to learn how to let two different applications running on different servers to communicate using REST

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by simply add a ForeignKey to the model of the second application, like this:

```
...
from appname.models import Patient
...

class YourModel(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, ...)
```

Like this whenever you need it you can do: `yourmodelinstance.patient.any_patient_field`

Comment: see actually what i'm trying has no practical use but i just want to learn how to let two different applications running on different servers to communicate using REST

Comment: you should explain better in your questions XD!